# compilation error in eclipse IDE for a java program

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

I have following code for which eclipse giving following compilation error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The hierarchy of the type TutorialsApplication is inconsistent
- The type com.vaadin.terminal.Terminal$ErrorListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
 from required .class files
- The type com.vaadin.terminal.URIHandler cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

and my code is :

```
package com.example.tutorials;

import com.example.component.Window.HomeWindow;
import com.vaadin.Application;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TutorialsApplication extends Application {
    // @Override
    public void init() {
        HomeWindow main = new HomeWindow("Welcome to FunFusion Content Management System");
        setMainWindow(main);
        main.initWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that the vaadin library, whatever it may be, depends on some third-party JAR file or files, which must be present in your CLASSPATH when you compile and run your application, but which you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a version of the Vaadin JAR included in your application that is not the same as the version of the Vaadin Eclipse plugin that you are using.
Try [updating](http://vaadin.com/download) both.